# Namespace collision in TYPO3

Tags: namespaces, typo3, extbase

I have a strange behavior in some of my TYPO3 Extensions I developed myself. I'm using TYPO3 Version > 6.2 and 7.6 with Extbase and Namespaces. Everything worked fine at the beginning, if an Extension was developed seperately. Now 'm using some of my Extensions together (at the same time) on the Production system. It seems that some Viewhelpers as well as some Services (same class name, different namespace) conflicts. How is this possible? I checked all namespace declerations and class names....

Short Example:
I'm using  an ExcelServices in Ext1 and Ext2 with some internal changes.
If both Extensions are installed Ext2 is using the ExcelService from Ext1 and prodruces an exception, because of missing input data.
Example 1:

```
PHP Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/dev7/typo3conf/ext/ext1/Resources/Private/Libs/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php
```

Example 2:

## 1289386765: Could not analyse class:PCON\Ext1\ViewHelpers\Form\TcaSelectedOptionsViewHelper maybe not loaded or no autoloader?

Both Erros Msg were called by Ext2.
Has someone a hint?

Comment: Seems to be a class loading issue rather than a conflict. Are you using TYPO3 in composer mode?

Comment: Hi!
No I don't use composer mode. 
Currently, I agree with you, the problems looks more than a caching/loading issue. I Cleared the cache and deleted the typo3temp and rebuild the autoload_classmap. Now I see the Problem: for example I'm using the PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 Class (which is not using namespaces) in several Projects (Extensions) so it will be loaded multiple times, but without namespaces only the the File/Class of the last loaded Extension will be used.